# Does a 4-pin XLR cable actually contain 4 separate conductors? Alternatives?

Tags: connector, cable-assemblies

Sounds like a dumb question but isn't, I think. While researching the possibility of using 4-pin XLR cables to hook together an LED stage lighting project, some catalogue pages seem to imply many 4-pin XLR cables (specifically, those used to carry power for video equipment) only contain 2 conductors.

Do *any* 4-pin XLR cables actually contain 4 separate conductors? How can I tell which are which?

Alternatively, can anyone suggest a readily available 4-conductor stage-proof cable/connector type? I need to transmit relatively high DC current (10A@5V) plus two signal wires (clock, data) over runs of 2-3m. I would much prefer buying cable assemblies off the shelf rather than making up my own as I need quite a few of them.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes.

The 4-pin XLR cable is popular with intercom headset systems. Two pins are used for the mono headphone signal and two pins for the unbalanced microphone signal, the cables will have all four populated for this purpose. However, it's audio and low-power so the conductor thickness (current carrying capacity) is typically smaller than you would need. There are 4-pin power cables, but these, as you note, do not always have all four and when they do sometimes the off-pair is a smaller diameter designed for a control signal (like synchronizing flash systems in photography -- just a low-power sync signal that triggers the high-current load on the other conductor pair).

Some Audio XLR cables contain all three circuits (conductors) through wired and you have an outer braided shielding that is isolated from the three circuits giving you potentially four independent electrical networks if you desired to use it that way. Audio cables can be designed for very high audio powers and low signal losses over long distances and may be sized big enough to carry your 10A DC with sufficiently low voltage loss.

But... as you observed, conductor quality and inclusion varies greatly among manufacturers and product lines. Best to open a sample up and inspect it to be sure.

### Check out machine cable assemblies

Industrial/factory automation equipment has similar demands to your application and therefore their standard products will also serve you well enough.

For example, "[Brad M12](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=microchange_m12_connectors&channel=PRODUCTS&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction)" connector systems are quite popular. But, be careful there is a range of conductors used with this type of connector and not all of them can handle your 10A requirement.

Answer (score 1):

> DC current (10A@5V) plus two signal wires (clock, data)

*you said 'project' so I assume you are building it rather than buying it*

Multiplexing is your friend here. Signals on top of power are accomplished with a couple of capacitors, you can get really fancy and use negative pulses for clock and positive for data.

In any stage situation you will have XLR cable by the mile readily available. 4 or 5 pin XLR exist, but as you have discovered not always in straight-through configuration.

Another thing to consider is that you don't need to source your power from the same place as your control. Run two lines to the instruments from separate palces, wire them with opposite-gender plugs. Both male and female panel mounts are readily available.

Also check out the Neutrik line of speaker connectors. Easy to assemble, (almost) indestructible, and (very important) rentable.

Comment: I am building it, yes; I'm not in a position to multiplex signals on top of power though. I don't have the expertise. The physical layout means I basically do have to source my power from the same place as the signal unfortunately.

Comment: Good call on the Neutrik speaker connectors though, they just might work (screw terminals too!): http://www.neutrik.com/en/speakon/spx-series/nl4fx

Comment: After poking around a bit more, we've gone with the Neutrik powerCON line, they are excellent: http://www.neutrik.com/en/audio/powercon/powercon/powercon-true1/